# linux server create symbolic links from filenames

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to write a shell script to run as a cron task, or preferably on creation of a file in a certain folder.

I have an `incoming` and an `outgoing` folder (they will be used to log mail). There will be files created with codes as follows...

`bmo-001-012-dfd-11` for outgoing and `012-dfd-003-11` for incoming. I need to filter the project/client code (`012-dfd`) and then place it in a folder in the specific project folder.

Project folders are located in `/projects` and follow the format `012-dfd`. I need to create symbolic links inside the incoming or outgoing folders of the projects, that leads to the correct file in the general `incoming` and `outgoing` folders.

```
/incoming/012-dfd-003-11.pdf -> /projects/012-dfd/incoming/012-dfd-003-11.pdf
/outgoing/bmo-001-012-dfd-11.pdf -> /projects/012-dfd/outgoing/bmo-001-012-dfd-11.pdf
```

So my questions

1. How would I make my script run when a file is added to either incoming or outgoing folder

   1. Additionally, is there any associated disadvantages with running upon file modification compared with running as cron task every 5 mins
2. How would I get the filename of recent (since script last run) files
3. How would I extract the code from the filename
4. How would I use the code to create a symlink in the desired folder

---

EDIT: What I ended up doing...

```
while inotifywait outgoing; do find -L . -type l -delete; ls outgoing | php -R '
if(
    preg_match("/^\w{3}-\d{3}-(\d{3}-\w{3})-\d{2}(.+)$/", $argn, $m)
    && $m[1] && (file_exists("projects/$m[1]/outgoing/$argn") != TRUE)
){
    `ln -s $(pwd)/outgoing/$argn projects/$m[1]/outgoing/$argn;`;
}
'; done;
```

This works quite well - cleaning up deleted symlinks also (with `find -L . -type l -delete`) but I would prefer to do it without the overhead of calling php. I just don't know bash well enough yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some near-answers for your task breakdown:

1. On linux, use [inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify), possibly through one of its [command-line tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki/), or [script language bindings](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify).
2. See above
3. Assuming the project name can be extracted thinking positionally from your examples (meaning not only does the project name follows a strict 7-character format, but what *precedes* it in the outgoing file also does):

   ```
   echo `basename /incoming/012-dfd-003-11.pdf` | cut -c 1-7
   012-dfd
   echo `basename /outgoing/bmo-001-012-dfd-11.pdf`| cut -c 9-15
   012-dfd
   ```
4. - `mkdir -p /projects/$i/incoming/` creates directory `/projects/012-dfd/incoming/` if `i = 012-dfd`,
   - `ln -s /incoming/foo /projects/$i/incoming/foo` creates a symbolic link from the latter argument, to the preexisting, former file `/incoming/foo`.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> How would I make my script run when a file is added to either incoming or outgoing folder
>     Additionally, is there any associated disadvantages with running upon file modification compared with running as cron task
> ```
>
> every 5 mins

If a 5 minutes delay isn't an issue, I would go for the cron job (it's easier and -IMHO- more flexible)

> How would I get the filename of recent (since script last run) files

If your script runs every 5 minutes, then you can tell that all the files created in between now (and now - 5 minutes) are newso, using the command *ls* or *find* you can list those files.

> How would I extract the code from the filename

You can use the *sed* command

> How would I use the code to create a symlink in the desired folder

Once you have the desired file names, you can usen *ln -s* command to create the symbolic link